# When does a child resolver get called?

Tags: graphql, apollo, graphql-js

If there is already all fields present in parent resolver, does child resolver get called even then?

```
query {
   users {
     firstName
     lastName
     fullName
   }
}
```

Here I have child resolver for `fullName`.

```
 Query: {
   users: async (_, data, ctx) {
    return UsersService.getUserById(ctx, data);   
   },
   User: {
    fullName(user, ctx) => `${user.firstName} ${user.lastName}`
   }
}
```

Here if `getUserById()` returns `fullName` already, does `fullName()` get called even then?

Comment: Was wondering the same thing. Any info?